# How send emails with Mautic with a custom text using API?

Tags: mautic

Is possible to add a custom text to a email before send it using mautic API.

We have an website where users may be notified when they receive a Gift. I would like to them receive this email with te gift name and price info.

This event is dispatched every time a gift is purchased, An email is sent by [MauticAPI](https://developer.mautic.org/?php#send-email-to-contact) like :

```
$response = $emailApi->sendToContact($emailId, $contactId);
```

But I would like to add the gift name and price in the email body. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to add custom content to email is by using tokens.
You can find more details here: https://developer.mautic.org/#extending-emails

You need to send in the body of the API request somethink like:

```
{
    "tokens": {
        "gift_name": "Cool Gift",
        "price": "$20"
    }
}
```

Then, in your email you can simply insert tokens using {}.

Example: 
You successfully purchased {gift_name} for {price}

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this! It really helped.

Comment: Could you please give some more details about usage ? at that address documentation it's very vague. maybe few lines of code would bring more clarity !